# find if filename contains a certain string in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of output files in a directory, such as: a.out, b.out c.out, etc.

I want to search through the output files and if the output *file name* contains a certain string (such as "a"), then it will print the corresponding output file "a.out" to screen.

After I cd-ed into the output files directory, here's my code:

```
OUT_FILE="*.out"
OT=$OUT_FILE
STRING="a"

for file in "$OT";do
  if [[$file == *"$STRING"*]];then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

The error I received is [[*.out: command not found. It looks like $file is interpreted as $OT, not as individual files that matches $OT.

But when I removed the if statement and just did a for-loop to echo each $file, the output gave me all the files that ended with .out.

Would love some help to understand what I did wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Wildcards (like `*.out`) aren't expanded inside double-quotes or on the right side of an assignment, so yours never gets converted to a list of files (until you `echo` it without double-quotes). Also, you *need* spaces between `[[`, the elements of the comparison, and `]]`. Spaces are critical delimiters in the shell; do not leave them out.

Comment: Space -- the final frontier.

Answer (score 24):

You need space after `[[` and before `]]`:

```
for file in *.out;do
  if [[ "$file" == *"$STRING"* ]];then
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
  fi
done
```

or just

```
for file in *"$STRING"*.out; do
    printf '%s\n' "$file"
done
```

or

```
printf '%s\n' *"$STRING"*.out
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `'%s\n`? Thanks!

Comment: @katiayx `%s` is the `printf` format specifier for "a string". The `%s` acts like a placeholder for the next argument on the command line. The value of the next argument will replace `%s` in the output. The `\n` will be replaced by a newline.  If `printf` is given more argument than placeholders in the format string, the format string will be reused.

Comment: @Kusalananda We need to check for particular directory also, Where we can mention directory path

Comment: @BhageshArora If the directory path is in `DIRPATH`, then use `for file in "$DIRPATH"/*"$STRING"*.out; do ...; done`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not working propery, cursor is going in both if and else condition. Inside the for loop.

Comment: @BhageshArora I was not considering the first code block with the `if` at all as the `if` test is not needed. Instead, what I was suggesting was to insert the directory path in the `for` loop in the second code block. I don't know what you mean about the "cursor going in". I'm not fond of doing interactive debugging sessions in comment threads, as it really has nothing to do with my answer but with a new issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda Here I mean to say printing both if & else condition print statement. $for file in "/tmp/home/My_location" *.ctl; do           
>if [[ "$file" == "mystring"* ]]; then
>printf "$file"
> else
> printf "else"
> fi
> done

Answer (score 6):

Without bashisms like `[[` (works in any Bourne-heritage shell) and blindingly fast since it does not fork any utility program:

```
for file in *.out; do
  case $file in
    (*a*) printf '%s\n' "$file";;
  esac
done
```

If you want you can replace `(*a*)` with `(*$STRING*)`.

Alternative if you have a `find` that understands `-maxdepth 1`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*"$STRING"\*.out
```

PS: Your question is a bit unclear. The code you posted tests for `a` in the **file name** (and so does my code). But your text suggests you want to search for `a` in the **file contents**. Which is it? Can you clarify?

Comment: My goal is to search for `a` in the **file name**. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @katiayx Then the easiest is probably `for i in *"$STRING"*.out; do echo "$i"; done`, assuming there is at least one match.